# Android Edit content in WebView

Tags: android, text, webview, edit

I have pictures/movies in my webview, and i have a problem with the resize.

I have a CSS for my webview in which i set

```
img{width:100%;}
```

But how to set the just height ? Because currently I have picture which take the half of the screen.

My other problem is i have

```
&nbsp;
```

in my content, how can I delete it ?

Comment: You need to add a lot more information for us to even have a chance to help you. Explain what you are trying to do in the first place. Is the content displayed in the `WebView` from you? As in can you edit it? Also tell us what you tried so far to fix it.

Comment: i'm taking contents from a WebService. I tried nothing, because i don't know what i have to do... :/

Comment: What do you mean by web service? I doubt that. Which web service returns HTML?

Comment: i can't explain you what's a webservice..i'm sorry, but the problem is not about the WS, because as i said, i can't modify it. SO i need to found a solution in my app.

Comment: I'm just confused as to what you are trying to do. You talk about a Web service but your question is about modifying a HTML in a `WebView`. I don't see any connection between those two things.

Comment: i'm taking my content from a webservice which returns jSON. (but in this jSON i've HTML with text)

Comment: I understand in that case I think the simplest solution is to load the HTML with a custom css. If you want to remove the `&nbsp;` elements you could simply use `String.replace("&nbsp;", "");` but you have to be carefull with all of that. Modifying HTML is just like HTML parsing a big source of bugs and rather error prone.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the styling of the HTML you could load a custom css like this:

```
final String customCssLink = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\">";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", customCssLink + html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

And you can remove all of the `&nbsp;` from the HTML like this:

```
String.replace("&nbsp;", "");
```

But with both those things you have to be very careful. Modifying HTML is just like HTML parsing a big source of bugs and rather error prone. If at all possible I would advice against  doing stuff like this, but if you have no other choice try to at least be as careful as possible.

Comment: ok, but i'm loading a custom css currently, but i don't know what to write to have a good "height" for my pictures etc...

Comment: I advise against setting the height. But it all depends on what you want it to look like. I can't tell how to design your app. I can only  help you if you explain to me what you want to do.

Comment: i don't know how to explain that, i just want to have my news with picture, but i don't want to have pictures whick takes the half of the screen, it's not very "beautiful"..

Comment: String.replace("&nbsp;", ""); it doesn't work, i have again "&nbsp;" in my webview :/

Comment: Yeah well how big do you want it to be? Just play around with some values until you find something you like. Maybe go for 50% and center the image. You can do whatever you want. You just first need an idea who it should look like.

Comment: Of course `String.replace("&nbsp;", "");` works. Is it possible that this is part of the text and encoded in the HTML? This would be an error in the HTML you receive, in other words not your problem. But if you want to fix it anyway you just need to replace the encoded `String` like this: `String.replace("&amp;nbsp;", "");`

Comment: The problem is, if i said a value like "height/50%;" depending the phone and the screen, the picture will be very bad :/ I want to "save" the quality of this picture

Comment: What do you mean the picture will be bad? No it won't, just because you display it smaller doesn't mean that somehow the quality of the image is getting reduced.

Comment: Ok ok, i will try it, thanks. I try to do String.replace("&amp;nbsp;", ""); but the problem is still here :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53825/discussion-between-xaver-kapeller-and-develost)